# App not releasing the memory, Memory use is getting doubled every time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I have created a function that help to find duplicate files in an array of `NSString` (array contains the file paths)

here is my function:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)compareWithList:(NSMutableArray*)fileCompareList // list of file from which we need to find the duplicates of the target
                          fileData:(NSData*)_fileData // contains target file data bytes
                        fileLength:(UInt32) _fileLenght // contains size of target file
{
    // result list of the (duplcate)files
    NSMutableArray* fileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // flag to check if the path is a folder
    BOOL isDir;

    //stores the size of the file that is being itrated
    UInt32 size = 0;
    //stores the byte data of the file that is being itrated
    NSData *bytes = nil;

    //itrating the files in the list one by one in order find the duplicate
    for (NSString* sPath in fileCompareList) {
        //checking if the file already exists in the result list
        if ([fileList indexOfObject:sPath] == NSNotFound)
        {
            //getting the size of the file
            UInt32 size = [sysHelp getSizeOfFile:sPath];
            //if the size matches of the target file and the itrated file then go inside
            if(size == _fileLenght)
            {
                //get the bytes of the file being itrated
                bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sPath];

                //if the bytes matches then add the itrated file into the result list
                if([bytes isEqualToData:_fileData])
                {
                    [fileList addObject:sPath];
                }
                //remove the itrated file data from the array
                bytes = nil;
            }
        }

    }

    return fileList;
}
```

Here the problem is that because of the function memory use is getting to high as shown in the screen shot below:

**before**
[image]

**after**
[image]

**after some time**
[image]

Note; I am using ARC
[image]

**How am I calling the funciton? here it is:**

```
NSMutableArray* allFilesOfSystem =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
allFilesOfSystem = self AllFilesOfDesktopAndSubDirectores];

NSMutableArray* FinalResultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [allFilesOfSystem count]; i++) {

        NSString* filePath = [allFilesOfSystem objectAtIndex:i];

        //file to byte array
        NSData *bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        //file size
        UInt32 size = [sysHelp getSizeOfFile:filePath];

        [FinalResultArray addObjectsFromArray:[self compareWithList:allFilesOfSystem fileData:bytes fileLength:size]]

}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of a thing called autorelease?

Comment: @ElTomato Have you heard of Automatic Reference Counting?

Comment: @ElTomato I am very new to objective-c and have background of .net technologies. I hope you understand. Please let me know how to solve this riddle. Note:  I am using ARC

Comment: @Droppy I am not able to use autorelease as ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'

Comment: @VikasBansal It wasn't me that suggested using `autorelease`.

Comment: Oh! @Droppy many pardons. As you asked if I am using  Automatic Reference Counting. the answer is Yes I am using. I have added screenshot in the question

Comment: Oh dear.  I didn't ask you that either.  I was responding to ElTomato.

Comment: Droppy simply said to El Tomato that *he* should read something about ARC before telling others to read about autorelease.

Comment: What let you think that memory is wasted? The memory usage bar says that the amount of RAM is fetched from system. It does not say that it is occupied by the App. What happens, if the memory usage gets a "dangerous" value? Hundreds of MB are not dangerous.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I am calling this function about 1000 time to find all the duplicate files from my system. The memory usage get doubled when I call this funciton. Memory reaches to 2gb+ while the application is running and scanning for the duplicate files.

Comment: Did you ever get a memory warning? What are 2 GB of RAM in a modern computer, when one App is consuming memory? Why should one free it, if there is no other one that can use it?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I am not sure. but i have not recived any prompt or message box as a warning. I am 1 month new to Xcode.

Comment: Try using +dataWithContentsOfFile: methods instead allocating a new NSData instance by yourself and compare memory usage. It takes sometimes for system to free up released memory so instead scanning all files in a single for loop you can scan files in batches say batch of 10 files.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad i have mac-book-pro having 4gb ram. I have updated question and added a screenshot of high memory usage.

Comment: @devgr  bytes = [[NSData alloc] dataWithContentsOfFile:sPath];  this code is saying that " No visible @ interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'dataWithContentsOfFile:'"

Comment: @VikasBansal it a static method so write like [NSdata dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath].

Comment: @devgr If I understood Vikas correctly the memory usage raises over many calls of that method. Beside this you solution would delay the deallocation of the instance. (Because it is created in the ARP.)

Comment: @VikasBansal I still cannot see the problem you have. Do you call the method 1000 times from program? However, if you get a problem, you should use `@autorelease {}`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad auto release is forbidden in ARC.

Comment: @devgr issue still persist even if I used dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Why it would delay the deallocation of instance? I am suggesting for batch processing so that system can take some air and free up the memory. I am not sure how many files he is passing into the function and how is he calling that function multiple times?

Comment: @VikasBansal does calling this function also freeze the app?

Comment: @devgr I really do not know whether it is batched or in a loop. However, using a convenience allocator always moves the instance object into the ARP, what is a delay.

Comment: @VikasBansal I did *not* say `autorelease`, I said `@autorelease{}`.

Comment: @devgr i have added how I am calling the function

Comment: Simply do, what @Inder stole from my comments.

Comment: @VikasBansal If autoreleasepool works for you then wrap the calling function code with autoreleasepool  (you added to question in the end) because I see you are also allocating NSData instance there.

Comment: @devgr ok sir, as you say. Thanks you all devgr, amin, inder, droppy, El for huge support. may god bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move all your statements in `@ autoreleasepool` and let me know if that helps. Below is the code

```
-(NSMutableArray *)compareWithList:(NSMutableArray*)fileCompareList // list of file from which we need to find the duplicates of the target
                          fileData:(NSData*)_fileData // contains target file data bytes
                        fileLength:(UInt32) _fileLenght // contains size of target file
{
  // result list of the (duplcate)files
  NSMutableArray* fileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  
  @autoreleasepool {
    // flag to check if the path is a folder
    BOOL isDir;
    
    //stores the size of the file that is being itrated
    UInt32 size = 0;
    //stores the byte data of the file that is being itrated
    NSData *bytes = nil;
    
    //itrating the files in the list one by one in order find the duplicate
    for (NSString* sPath in fileCompareList) {
      //checking if the file already exists in the result list
      if ([fileList indexOfObject:sPath] == NSNotFound)
      {
        //getting the size of the file
        UInt32 size = [sysHelp getSizeOfFile:sPath];
        //if the size matches of the target file and the itrated file then go inside
        if(size == _fileLenght)
        {
          //get the bytes of the file being itrated
          bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sPath];
          
          //if the bytes matches then add the itrated file into the result list
          if([bytes isEqualToData:_fileData])
          {
            [fileList addObject:sPath];
          }
          //remove the itrated file data from the array
          bytes = nil;
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
  return fileList;
}
```

---

#### Edit:Explanation

There are two ways to relinquish object's ownership. One is release and other is autorelease. If you call release to an object and if the retain count of the object becomes it is deallocated immediately, but if you autorelease an object the release message is sent once the autorelease pool is released/drained i.e. release is deferred. Lets take an example.

```
- (void)testMemoryInARC1 {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"myfile.mp3"]; // reatin count is 1
  //used this data an after few statements
  //statement 1
  // ..
  
  
  //at the end of data varibale scope in this case it's the end of method
  //ARC will insert the release call
  // [data rlease]; //wchich releases the memory
}


- (void)testMemoryInARC2 {
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"myfile.mp3"]; // this method returns the autorelase object
  //used this data an after few statements
  //statement 1
  // ..
  
  
  //at the end of data varibale scope in this case it's the end of method
  //ARC will NOT insert the release call since that was autoreleased object
  //hence no release call
}
```

***So the question comes when will it get released?***
ARS says, "Nice question, it will be released when auto release pool gets over (released)".

***When will auto release pool get over?***
ARC says, "Just check where is you have created autorelease pool, if you haven't created it then there is a main autorelease pool in `main.m` file"

***It means all the autorelease objects are released when main method finishes, how will that help me that's the end of program?***
ARC says, "Nice question again! Cocoa library has used the autorelease pool throughout the development if you haven't used it then sir it's your problem not mine."

#### [About Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Comment: it worked... it worked like a magic or a charm... omg!... please please.. how does it work???? please elaborate